# Random number between int.MinValue and int.MaxValue, inclusive

Tags: c#, .net, random

Here's a bit of a puzzler: `Random.Next()` has an overload that accepts a minimum value and a maximum value. This overload returns a number that is greater than or equal to the minimum value (inclusive) and less than the maximum value (exclusive).

I would like to include the entire range including the maximum value. In some cases, I could accomplish this by just adding one to the maximum value. But in this case, the maximum value can be `int.MaxValue`, and adding one to this would not accomplish what I want.

So does anyone know a good trick to get a random number from `int.MinValue` to `int.MaxValue`, inclusively?

**UPDATE:**

Note that the lower range can be `int.MinValue` but can also be something else. If I know it would always be `int.MinValue` then the problem would be simpler.

Comment: Use the overload with `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue`; if it ever produces `int.MaxValue - 1`, randomly add 1 :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey: But then it could never produce `int.MaxValue - 1`.

Comment: Yes it could. You would random between `int.MaxValue` and `int.MaxValue - 1` upon rolling an `int.MaxValue - 1`

Comment: @MattRowland: If you always replaced `int.MaxValue - 1` with `int.MaxValue`, as was suggested, then you would never return `int.MaxValue - 1`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey didn't say "always". They said "randomly".

Comment: Int.minValue and int.MaxValue are so far apart the chances of getting one of them randomally is so slim that it just might make this question nothing more than a nice exercise in logic with little to none effective value in real world applications. That being said, I do like this question (sorry for any mispells, using my cellphone)

Comment: Indeed, it was a bit of a joke. One might call it a random joke at that...

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I agree. I'm trying to write a general-purpose library. If it was for a specific task, I'm sure I could just patch by omitting `int.MaxValue` as a result or something like that. But as a general purpose library, I'm trying not to make assumptions about the callers requirements. I find it interesting because it's a small issue but tricky to solve.

Answer (score 17):

The [internal implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/random.cs.html#ddd1e9e09c70bab5) of `Random.Next(int minValue, int maxValue)` generates two samples for large ranges, like the range between `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue`. For the `NextInclusive` method I had to use another large range `Next`, totaling four samples. So the performance should be comparable with the version that fills a buffer with 4 bytes (one sample per byte).

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static int NextInclusive(this Random random, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        if (maxValue == Int32.MaxValue)
        {
            if (minValue == Int32.MinValue)
            {
                var value1 = random.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
                var value2 = random.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
                return value1 < value2 ? value1 : value1 + 1;
            }
            return random.Next(minValue - 1, Int32.MaxValue) + 1;
        }
        return random.Next(minValue, maxValue + 1);
    }

}
```

Some results:

```
new Random(0).NextInclusive(int.MaxValue - 1, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MaxValue
new Random(1).NextInclusive(int.MaxValue - 1, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MaxValue - 1
new Random(0).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MinValue + 1); // returns int.MinValue + 1
new Random(1).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MinValue + 1); // returns int.MinValue
new Random(24917099).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MinValue
var random = new Random(784288084);
random.NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
random.NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MaxValue
```

---

**Update:** My implementation has mediocre performance for the largest possible range (`Int32.MinValue` - `Int32.MaxValue`), so I came up with a new one that is 4 times faster. It produces around 22,000,000 random numbers per second in my machine. I don't think that it can get any faster than that.

```
public static int NextInclusive(this Random random, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    if (maxValue == Int32.MaxValue)
    {
        if (minValue == Int32.MinValue)
        {
            var value1 = random.Next() % 0x10000;
            var value2 = random.Next() % 0x10000;
            return (value1 << 16) | value2;
        }
        return random.Next(minValue - 1, Int32.MaxValue) + 1;
    }
    return random.Next(minValue, maxValue + 1);
}
```

Some results:

```
new Random(0).NextInclusive(int.MaxValue - 1, int.MaxValue); // = int.MaxValue
new Random(1).NextInclusive(int.MaxValue - 1, int.MaxValue); // = int.MaxValue - 1
new Random(0).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MinValue + 1); // = int.MinValue + 1
new Random(1).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MinValue + 1); // = int.MinValue
new Random(1655705829).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue); // = int.MaxValue
var random = new Random(1704364573);
random.NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
random.NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
random.NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue); // = int.MinValue
```

Comment: Are you taking into account that Random.Next() only returns positive numbers?

Comment: @JonathanWood I didn't use the `Random.Next()` overload that takes no arguments. I used the `Random.Next(int minValue, int maxValue)`. I could have used the `Next()` to reduce the samples to three instead of four, but this would complicate the math and I preferred to keep it simple.

Comment: I think, the question got enough attention. For now we have 3 answers of the highest score. One is mine. Another one is quite incomplete. So the award goes to this one. Thanks, everyone. Thank you, Theodor Zoulias.

Answer (score 11):

No casting, no `long`, all boundary cases taken into account, best performance.

```
static class RandomExtension
{
    private static readonly byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];

    public static int InclusiveNext(this Random random, int min, int max)
    {
        if (max < int.MaxValue)
            // can safely increase 'max'
            return random.Next(min, max + 1);

        // now 'max' is definitely 'int.MaxValue'
        if (min > int.MinValue)
            // can safely decrease 'min'
            // so get ['min' - 1, 'max' - 1]
            // and move it to ['min', 'max']
            return random.Next(min - 1, max) + 1;

        // now 'max' is definitely 'int.MaxValue'
        // and 'min' is definitely 'int.MinValue'
        // so the only option is
        random.NextBytes(bytes);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is no ideal solution to this, but this looks pretty good.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood, I guess so. But I'm looking forward to new good ideas. That's what the bounty is for)

Comment: If `min` and `max` are equal, should that really raise an exception? If you change your mind about that (or it wasn't actually intended), then you can safely get rid of the first check (and exception) because `Random.Next(int, int)` handles that for you (whenever `max < min`).

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed, I believe `Random.Next(a ,a)` is nonsense. It's just `a`. What's the point to call a method?

Comment: _"It unexpectedly returns `int.MaxValue - 1`"_ Umm, looks like it should return `int.MaxValue` just fine (because of your `random.Next(min - 1, max) + 1`). Just to be clear, I'm not saying that the decision of throwing an exception when `min == max` is necessarily (always) a bad one. However, it might not be expected by the developers using the library for a number of reasons (one of them is that it's _not_ the behavior of the existing method (i.e., `Random.Next(x, x)`). Although people would probably have (valid?) arguments for both directions.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed , yes, I checked, it works fine with two int.MaxValue.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed, I guess, you are right. The check is redundant and misleading. Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I have a trick. I'm not sure I'd describe it as a "good trick", but I feel like it might work.

```csharp
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static int NextInclusive(this Random rng, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        if (maxValue == int.MaxValue)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[4];
            rng.NextBytes(bytes);
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        }
        return rng.Next(minValue, maxValue + 1);
    }
}
```

So, basically an extension method that will simply generate four bytes if the upper-bound is `int.MaxValue` and convert to an `int`, otherwise just use the standard `Next(int, int)` overload.

**Note that if `maxValue` is `int.MaxValue` it will ignore `minValue`. Guess I didn't account for that...**

Comment: This ignores the lower bounds if `maxValue == int.MaxValue`, but I had wondered about something like this approach if I could refine it further.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that same thing after posting :(.

Comment: Extending on this, can you create int variable and set it to 0 and then set individual bits to 0 or 1 randomly to get a random number?

Answer (score 5):

Split the ranges in two, and compensate for the `MaxValue`:

```
r.Next(2) == 0 ? r.Next(int.MinValue, 0) : (1 + r.Next(-1, int.MaxValue))
```

If we make the ranges of equal size, we can get the same result with different math. Here we rely on the fact that `int.MinValue = -1 - int.MaxValue`:

```
r.Next(int.MinValue, 0) - (r.Next(2) == 0 ? 0 : int.MinValue)
```

Comment: I like this answer, its very simple and effective.

Comment: or it could be use the lower full-half-range [int.MinValue, 0) for both situations and reversed the sign for the positive numbers. That could simplify a bit the logic and would save the explanations you had to make later :)

Comment: @tgralex can't reverse the sign. abs(int.MinLength) != abs(int.MaxLength). By absolute value it's actually larger.

Comment: int.MaxValue:  2,147,483,647
int.MinValue: -2,147,483,648
Which means Abs(int.MinValue) = Abs(int.MaxValue)+1
so the range we are looking for is (-Abs(int.MinValue), +Abs(int.MinValue))
and because of that I was suggesting to simplify to:

var sign = (r.Next(2) == 0 ? 1 : 1);
return sign * r.Next(0, Abs(int.MinValue));

That is all. Its just looks slightly simpler to me :)

Comment: @tgralex it is not possible to give value `Abs(int.MinValue)` to `Next` because there is no such value. But suppose we call `Next(int.MinValue, 0)`, then you never get 0, but also reversing the sign causes the error if `Next` actually returns `MinValue`, because `-int.MinValue` does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `System.Numerics.BigInteger` like this:

```
class InclusiveRandom
{
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public byte Next(byte min, byte max) => (byte)NextHelper(min, max);
    public sbyte Next(sbyte min, sbyte max) => (sbyte)NextHelper(min, max);
    public short Next(short min, short max) => (short)NextHelper(min, max);
    public ushort Next(ushort min, ushort max) => (ushort)NextHelper(min, max);
    public int Next(int min, int max) => (int)NextHelper(min, max);
    public uint Next(uint min, uint max) => (uint)NextHelper(min, max);
    public long Next(long min, long max) => (long)NextHelper(min, max);
    public ulong Next(ulong min, ulong max) => (ulong)NextHelper(min, max);

    private BigInteger NextHelper(BigInteger min, BigInteger max)
    {
        if (max <= min)
            throw new ArgumentException($"max {max} should be greater than min {min}");

        return min + RandomHelper(max - min);
    }

    private BigInteger RandomHelper(BigInteger bigInteger)
    {
        byte[] bytes = bigInteger.ToByteArray();
        BigInteger random;

        do
        {
            rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
            bytes[bytes.Length - 1] &= 0x7F;
            random = new BigInteger(bytes);
        } while (random > bigInteger);

        return random;
    }
}
```

I tested it with `sbyte`.

```
var rnd = new InclusiveRandom();
var frequency = Enumerable.Range(sbyte.MinValue, sbyte.MaxValue - sbyte.MinValue + 1).ToDictionary(i => (sbyte)i, i => 0ul);
var count = 100000000;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    frequency[rnd.Next(sbyte.MinValue, sbyte.MaxValue)]++;
foreach (var i in frequency)
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i.Key, (double)i.Value / count);

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines
    .Add(new StripLine { Interval = 0, IntervalOffset = 1d / 256, StripWidth = 0.0003, BackColor = Color.Red });
```

Distribution is OK.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask the purpose of the line `bytes[bytes.Length - 1] &= 0x7F;`? It seems you are eliminating negative numbers?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood, here I try to get a random difference between a greater and a smaller number. This difference is always a positive number.

Comment: Yes, I see. You're adding it to the minimum value. Some concern about the performance here, but will play with this when I get a moment.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood, this code, no doubt, is subject to optimizations (e.g. for non-boundary conditions, where one do not deal with both min and max values), but it works in general way with all non-floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4):

This is guaranteed to work with negative and non-negative values:

```
public static int NextIntegerInclusive(this Random r, int min_value, int max_value)
{
  if (max_value < min_value)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("max_value must be greater than min_value.");
  }
  long offsetFromZero =(long)min_value; // e.g. -2,147,483,648
  long bound = (long)max_value; // e.g. 2,147,483,647
  bound -= offsetFromZero; // e.g. 4,294,967,295 (uint.MaxValue)
  bound += Math.Sign(bound); // e.g. 4,294,967,296 (uint.MaxValue + 1)
  return (int) (Math.Round(r.NextDouble() * bound) + offsetFromZero); // e.g. -2,147,483,648 => 2,147,483,647
}
```

Comment: This has bad distribution. `new Random().NextIntegerInclusive(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue)` will never return half of the numbers in this range. For example `Int32.MinValue + 1` and `Int32.MaxValue - 1` can never be produced by this method, provided that the [current implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/random.cs.html) of `Random` will remain unchanged.

Comment: I know there is a problem with System.Random, but the question was not how to fix System.Random. I already upvoted @Alex's answer above this, because it is a better answer. That should be the selected answer.

Comment: Don't blame `Random` for this. The `Random` class by itself can produce all integer numbers in a given range (admittedly without a perfectly fair distribution). Your implementation has much more severe issues!

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your first comment.Can you elaborate on why this will never return half the numbers in the range? I don't see what you are seeing.

Comment: Ah, @Theodor, I see the private `GetSampleForLargeRange()`. I was not aware of that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You found it.  I was about to say that it is impossible to map a set of 2,147,483,647 numbers to a set of 4,294,967,296 numbers with a one-to-one relationship!

Comment: Btw @Alex's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57208289/11178549) is indeed currently the best, but I am cooking an updated version of mine, hoping to beat him in performance. 

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it you want Random to put out a value between -2.147.483.648 and +2.147.483.647. But the problem is that Random given those values will only give values from -2.147.483.648 to +2.147.483.64**6**, as the maximum is exclusive.

**Option 0: Take the thing away and learn to do without it**

Douglas Adams was not a Programmer AFAIK, but he has some good advice for us: "The technology involved in making anything invisible is so infinitely complex that nine hundred and ninety-nine billion, nine hundred and ninety-nine million, nine hundred and ninety-nine thousand, nine hundred and ninety-nine times out of a trillion it is much simpler and more effective just to take the thing away and do without it."

This might be such a case.

**Option 1: We need a bigger Random!**

Random.Next() uses Int32 as Argument. One option I can think off would be to use a different Random Function Which can take the next higher level of Integers (Int64) as input. An Int32 is implicitly cast into an Int64. `Int64 Number = Int64(Int32.MaxValue)+1;`

But afaik, you would have to go outside of .NET libraries to do this. At that point, you might as well look for a Random that is inclusive of the Max.

But I think there is a mathematical reason it had to exclude one value.

**Option 2: Roll more**

Another way is to use two calls of Random - each for one half of the range - and then add them.

```
Number1 = rng.Next(-2.147.483.648, 0);
Number2 = rng.Next(0, 2.147.483.647);
resut = Number1 + Number2;
```

However, I am 90% certain that will ruin the random distribution. My P&P RPG experience gave me some experience with dice chances and I know for a fact rolling 2 dice (or the same 2 times) will get you a very different result distribution than one specific die. If you do not need this random distribution, that is an option. But if you do not care too much about the distribution it is worth a check.

**Option 3: Do you need the full range? Or do you just care for min and max to be in it?**

I assume you are doing some form of testing and you need both Int.MaxValue and Int.MinValue to be in the range. But do you need every value **in between** as well, or could you do without one of them?
If you have to lose value, would you prefer loosing 4 rather then Int.MaxValue?

```
Number = rng.Next(Int.MinValue, Int.MaxValue);
if(Number > 3)
  Number = Number +1;
```

code like this would get you every number between MinValue and MaxValue, **except 4**. But in most cases code that can deal with 3 and 5 can also deal with 4. There is no need to explicitly test 4.

Of course, that assumes 4 is not some important test number that has to be run (I avoided 1 and 0 for those reasons). You could also decide the number to "skip" Randomly:

```
skipAbleNumber = rng.Next(Int.MinValue +1, Int.MaxValue);
```

And then use `> skipAbleNumber` rather than `> 4`.

Comment: As I've explained elsewhere, I am writing a general-purpose library. So it wouldn't be enough to say I don't need this number of that number. I need to allow for what the users of the library might need. And I've determined it makes better sense to be inclusive of the result range. So, for most people, it just becomes a little bit more of a mental puzzle than an every day programming task.

Comment: @JonathanWood: The advantage of Option 3 is that the user does not need to bother how the number is generated. And it *should* still follow the basic rules of statistical distirbution. But to be certain, better ask the Math guys - this is way beyond my Math Skill Level. The only other option is to write your own Random Number Generator. At wich point you propably learn why one number was excluded to begin with.

Comment: @JonathanWood: As I suspected, Javas Inter Random also has the exclusivity Limitation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html And C++ Random seems to ignore anything below 0: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand My guess is interally they are using some math involving a unsigned Int32 and the value can **not** be 0 or Max for this math.

Comment: The user would be expecting all numbers in the range to be possible results. That's the part the concerns me, not how the number is generated. As far as why `Random.Next()` is not inclusive of the maximum value, it may simplify the algorithm but it's also useful in many cases. For example, if you are using the result as an index into a collection.

Comment: @JonathanWood "The user would be expecting all numbers in the range to be possible results. That's the part the concerns me, not how the number is generated." I expected the result of Random.Next to be inclusive. Turns out they are not. And a quick check reveals this seem shared across all higher Langauges. Interpreted Script Languages seem to be a bit more loose with this. My current guess is that you can **not** ignore how the number is generated because that is the **reason** not every value can be included.

Comment: I was responding to your comment *"The advantage of Option 3 is that the user does not need to bother how the number is generated"*, and went on to ask *"But do you need every value in between as well?"*. I'm addressing the issue of leaving out some numbers in between. I do not believe the caller would expect that unless I went out of my way to document it as behaving that way.

Comment: @JonathanWood: But in the modified version it is random wich number is skipped. Literally as random as the number generated, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually interesting that this isn't the implementation for Random.Next(int, int), because you can derive the behavior of exclusive from the behavior of inclusive, but not the other way around.

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    private const long IntegerRange = (long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue;

    public static int NextInclusive(this Random random, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue > maxValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(minValue));
        }

        var buffer = new byte[4];
        random.NextBytes(buffer);
        var a = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        var b = a - (long)int.MinValue;
        var c = b * (1.0 / IntegerRange);
        var d = c * ((long)maxValue - minValue + 1);
        var e = (long)d + minValue;
        return (int)e;
    }
}
```

```
new Random(0).NextInclusive(int.MaxValue - 1, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MaxValue
```

```
new Random(1).NextInclusive(int.MaxValue - 1, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MaxValue - 1
```

```
new Random(0).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MinValue + 1); // returns int.MinValue + 1
```

```
new Random(1).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MinValue + 1); // returns int.MinValue
```

```
new Random(-451732719).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MinValue
```

```
new Random(-394328071).NextInclusive(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue); // returns int.MaxValue
```

Answer (score 1):

This method can give you a random integer within any integer limits. If the maximum limit is less than int.MaxValue, then it uses the ordinary Random.Next(Int32, Int32) but with adding 1 to upper limit to include its value. If not but with lower limit greater than int.MinValue, it lowers the lower limit with 1 to shift the range 1 less that add 1 to the result. Finally, if both limits are int.MinValue and int.MaxValue, it generates a random integer 'a' that is either 0 or 1 with 50% probability of each, then it generates two other integers, the first is between int.MinValue and -1 inclusive, 2147483648 values, and the second is between 0 and int.MaxValue inclusive , 2147483648 values also, and using them with the value of 'a' it select an integer with totally equal probability.

```
private int RandomInclusive(int min, int max)
{
    if (max < int.MaxValue)
        return Random.Next(min, max + 1);
    if (min > int.MinValue)
        return Random.Next(min - 1, max) + 1;
    int a = Random.Next(2);
    return Random.Next(int.MinValue, 0) * a + (Random.Next(-1, int.MaxValue) + 1) * (1 - a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I don't think `int.MinValue - 1` would produce the expected result.

Comment: This doesn't work as the min would wrap back to the max.

Comment: `yourmin - 1` with overflow if it's `int.MinValue`.

Comment: Sorry I missed minValue.
Try this new one.

Comment: The first part will give you a random integer between int.MinValue and 0 exclusively, and the second one will give a random integer between 0 and int.MaxValue exclusively, so together the range will be all integers from int.MinValue and int.MaxValue exclusively. Why do you think it will not be applicable?

Comment: This is random, but not evenly distributed.  But maybe that's okay.

Comment: He didn't ask for an evenly distributed random integer. :)

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef: A non-evenly distributed random integer is not very random.

Comment: @JonathanWood I dunno about that.  I suspect some people could argue that the sum of two rolled dice was random, but not evenly distributed.  Here's a question/answer that gets into the semantics of this: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20839/what-is-the-difference-between-uniformly-and-at-random-in-crypto-definitions

Interestingly, I wrote my dice example before I searched for a question/answer...turns out the second answer uses this exact example.

Comment: @Beska: Well, interesting discussion but to me, if the results favor a certain pattern then they are not truly random. That said, I'm using the `Random` class so we're talking about pseudo random anyway.

Comment: @JonathanWood How about this one?

Comment: @Alex What do think about this?

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Random rnd = new Random();
      int min_value = max_value;
      int max_value = min_value;
      Console.WriteLine("\n20 random integers from 10 to 20:");
      for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 20; ctr++) 
      {
         Console.Write("{0,6}", rnd.Next(min_value, max_value));
         if (ctr % 5 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try it with `min_value = int.MinValue; max_value = int.MaxValue`, per my question. It won't produce the correct results. I'm not sure you understood the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. A bit hacky but can get you both min and max inclusive.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    var r = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        x = x | (r.Next(0, 2) << i);
     Console.WriteLine(x);
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, appreciate the suggestion but this is not very performant, in addition to being hacky. I would at least use `Random.NextBytes()` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
int random(Random rnd, int min, int max) 
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(rnd.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this returns max. Mathematically, you have 0.0 <= Random.NextDouble() < 1.0 ----> 0 <= value < max - min ----> min <= value < max, so value will never be able to reach max.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `Random.Next()` to achieve what you want, because you can not correspond sequence of `N` numbers to `N+1` and not miss one :). Period.

But you can use `Random.NextDouble()`, which returns double result:
`0 <= x < 1`  aka `[0, 1)`
between 0, where `[` is inclusive sign and `)` exclusive

How do we correspond N numbers to [0, 1)? 
You need to split `[0, 1)` to N equal segments: 
`[0, 1/N)`, `[1/N, 2/N)`, ... `[N-1/N, 1)`

And here is where it becomes important that one border is inclusive and another is exclusive - all N segments are absolutely equal!

**Here is my code:** I made it as a simple console program.

```
class Program
    {
        private static Int64 _segmentsQty;
        private static double _step;
        private static Random _random = new Random();

        static void Main()
        {
            InclusiveRandomPrep();
            for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(InclusiveRandom());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void InclusiveRandomPrep()
        {
            _segmentsQty = (Int64)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue;
            _step = 1.0 / _segmentsQty;
        }
        public static int InclusiveRandom()
        {
            var randomDouble = _random.NextDouble();
            var times = randomDouble / _step;
            var result = (Int64)Math.Floor(times);
            return (int)result + int.MinValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are suggesting. An example would certainly help to clarify.

Comment: Updated. Check it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `1` to generated number randomly so it still random and cover full range integer.

```
public static class RandomExtension
{
    public static int NextInclusive(this Random random, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        var randInt = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        var plus = random.Next(0, 2);
        return randInt + plus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's random. But what about probability? Does it remain equal?

Comment: Why `var randInt = random.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);` but not `var randInt = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);`?

Comment: @JonathanWood it could return minValue, why not?

Comment: @Alex, no, the probability distribution is not uniform. To get 5, for example, `randInt` and `plus` could either be (5 and 0) or (4 and 1). But to get `int.MinValue` they can only be (`int.MinValue` and 0). And to get `int.MaxValue` they can only be (`int.MaxValue` - 1 and 1). The two extremes have half the probability of other values.