# Is this a bug in Partitioner.Create(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, partitioning

I think I discovered a bug in the method [`Partitioner.Create(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create#System_Collections_Concurrent_Partitioner_Create_System_Int32_System_Int32_). It calculates negative values for the non-provided argument `rangeSize`, when the range exceeds `Int32.MaxValue`. Here is a code sample that demonstrates the issue:

```
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(-1, Int32.MaxValue);
var partitions = partitioner.GetPartitions(1);
foreach (var partition in partitions)
{
    while (partition.MoveNext())
    {
        var range = partition.Current;
        Console.WriteLine($"Range: {range.Item1,11} => {range.Item2,11}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Range:          -1 =>  -178956971
Range:  -178956971 =>  -357913941
Range:  -357913941 =>  -536870911
Range:  -536870911 =>  -715827881
Range:  -715827881 =>  -894784851
Range:  -894784851 => -1073741821
Range: -1073741821 => -1252698791
Range: -1252698791 => -1431655761
Range: -1431655761 => -1610612731
Range: -1610612731 => -1789569701
Range: -1789569701 => -1968526671
Range: -1968526671 => -2147483641
Range: -2147483641 =>  2147483647
```

So looping throw these ranges with `for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)` will result in zero loops for all but the last range, which will
loop effectively the full range of the `Int32` type.

There is a special case. The partitioner below calculates a `rangeSize` of 1.

```
Partitioner.Create(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Here is the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/concurrent/PartitionerStatic.cs.html#420c5a76227e3353) of the method:

```
public static OrderablePartitioner<Tuple<int, int>> Create(
    int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)
{
    // How many chunks do we want to divide the range into?  If this is 1, then the
    // answer is "one chunk per core".  Generally, though, you'll achieve better
    // load balancing on a busy system if you make it higher than 1.
    int coreOversubscriptionRate = 3;

    if (toExclusive <= fromInclusive) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("toExclusive");
    int rangeSize = (toExclusive - fromInclusive) /
        (PlatformHelper.ProcessorCount * coreOversubscriptionRate);
    if (rangeSize == 0) rangeSize = 1;
    return Partitioner.Create(CreateRanges(fromInclusive, toExclusive, rangeSize),
        EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering); // chunk one range at a time
}
```

It seems that an integer overflow occurs on the subtraction `toExclusive - fromInclusive`.

If this is a indeed bug, what workaround do you suggest until it is fixed in a future version of the .NET Framework?

Comment: @mjwills let me mention my use case. To backup [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133838/11178549) about the `Random` class I needed to loop throw all possible seeds, in search for special results. I used `Parallel.For` combined with `Partitioner.Create` to speed things up. Your suggestion of casting tο `long` is certainly an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that an integer overflow occurs on the division toExclusive -
>   fromInclusive.

Yes, it looks like it is a bug.

> What workaround do you suggest until it is fixed in a future version
>   of the .NET Framework?

I'd suggest casting your inputs to `long` and calling [that version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Concurrent_Partitioner_Create_System_Int64_System_Int64_) instead. *It still has a similar overflow bug, but if your original inputs are `int` you definitely won't run into an overflow scenario with `long`.*

Answer (score 3):

@mjwills is right.

This is a bug and I have logged an issue to get this fixed in the future releases of the .NET Core https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40201

And the suggested workaround is correct too. just cast the input parameters to long.