# Can Random.Next() ever return int.MaxValue?

Tags: c#

The documentation for the `Random.Next()` method states that it returns:

> A 32-bit signed integer that is greater than or equal to 0 and **less than MaxValue**.

But, I took a peek at the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs#L94-L114), and while I don't understand the algorithm (a quick Google search suggests that it is a *subtractive generator*), I can't see any way in which a value of exactly `int.MaxValue` is ruled out.

If, for pedantic reasons, someone wants a random number across the entire range of 32-bit integers, does `Random.Next()` alone suffice, or does it become necessary to do something like assemble two separate 16-bit samples?

Comment: Related: [Random number between int.MinValue and int.MaxValue, inclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118385/random-number-between-int-minvalue-and-int-maxvalue-inclusive)

Comment: Does "across the entire range of 32-bit integers" include negative values?

Comment: @HABO It does, and I was so focused on `int.MaxValue` I also missed that it only returns non-negative values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It will always be less than int.MaxValue.**

In your linked source code it explicitly handles int.MaxValue:

```
if (retVal == MBIG) retVal--;
```

MBIG is defined earlier:

```
private const int MBIG = int.MaxValue;
```

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs#L105

Comment: Oh shoot, I totally missed that. :-) Thanks!

Comment: That's actually really annoying, because it means you are twice as likely to get `int.MaxValue - 1` than any other value. :-P And this drives the entire `Random` class. Argh.

Comment: You're welcome. It jumped into my eye so I had to answer. ;-)

Comment: @JonathanGilbert if you ever need a better RNG, a good alternative is the [`C5Random`](https://c5docs.azurewebsites.net/classC5_1_1C5Random.html) class from the [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) package. It is an implementation of the [Marsaglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Marsaglia) algorithm.